# python - Get ith, jth and kth elements of a tuple in respective lists

Tags: python

I have a tuple with data like

```
results = ((a, b, c, d), (1, 2, 3, 4), (q, w, e, r))
```

I need 1st, 2nd and 3rd element in different lists like:

```
one = [a, 1, q]
two = [b. 2, w]
thr = [c, 3, e]
```

I am doing it like:

```
one = [r[0] for r in results]
two = [r[1] for r in results]
thr = [r[2] for r in results]
```

But I feel there would be a way to do this in a single line instead of three loops.

Other way I could think of is like

```
 for r in results:
    one.append(r[0])
    two.append(r[1])
    thr.append(r[2])
```

Is there any other better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use zip for this:

```
>>> for (one, two, thr) in zip(*results):
...   print (one, two, thr)
... 
a 1 q
b 2 w
c 3 e
d 4 r
```

If you are dealing with jagged lists and care about elements at the ends of the longer lists you should look at `zip_longest` in the itertools module.  It will produce similar results with a fill value (default of `None`) for the shorter lists.

Comment: That isn't what the OP asks for. The OP asks for `one` to become a list of the first items of the given tuples, `two` to become a list of the second items of the tuples, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can zip the sequence of tuples and then unpack the output of `zip` into separate variables:

```
one, two, thr, *_ = zip(*results)
```

so that:

```
print(one, two, thr, sep='\n')
```

outputs:

```
('a', '1', 'q')
('b', '2', 'w')
('c', '3', 'e')
```

If you need the resulting variables as lists instead you can map the output of `zip` to the `list` constructor:

```
one, two, thr, *_ = map(list, zip(*results))
```

so that:

```
print(one, two, thr, sep='\n')
```

outputs:

```
['a', '1', 'q']
['b', '2', 'w']
['c', '3', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use list comprehension this way

```
r = [[el[i] for el in results] for i in range(len(results))]
```

This give you a list of the list you want. Output :

```
[['a', 1, 'q'], ['b', 2, 'w'], ['c', 3, 'e']]
```

Comment: Any time you are using `range(len(collection))` you should _probably_ be leveraging `enumerate` instead.

Comment: It would fail in case of `results = (('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), (1, 2, 3, 4), ('q', 'w', 'e', 'r'), ('z', 'v', 'x', 'b'))`. As I only want first 3 elements.

Comment: You guys are right. I only focused on the case here, but @g.d.d.c answer is better.

Comment: @g.d.d.c How would that help here?

Comment: @HeapOverflow - I'm not certain it _would_ - this answer uses the index in a rather unrelated way to what the `range(len(...))` is producing, which is itself problematic.  The comment was more a generalized note, because _most_ times you see `range(len(...))` in python, the code can be made cleaner by `for idx, elm in enumerate(collection)`.